# Can you use mat-color with Angulars theme?

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I am using an Angular theme with my angular 9 app, I have an instance where I want to use mat-color lighter and darker (for color and backgroud-color respectively), I have gotten this to work before with a  custom theme but never with an Angular theme.

I have added

```
background-color: mat-color($color-error, lighter);
color: mat-color($color-error, darker);
```

to my css where $color-error is a variable I have created. The colors are not coming through to the class.

Any way I can use lighter or darker with mat-color?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is [an example I created on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thyura?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-overview-example.html) on how you can create a theme with angular and define lighter and darker color based on the palette color

Here is the important code :

theme.scss:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$custom-primary: mat-palette($mat-teal);
$custom-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$custom-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
$custom-theme:   mat-light-theme($custom-primary, $custom-accent, $custom-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($custom-theme);
```

In this file I create a custom theme and define a light theme.

variables.scss:

```
@import './theme.scss';

$primary: mat-color($custom-primary);
$primary-lighter: mat-color($custom-primary, lighter);
$primary-darker: mat-color($custom-primary, darker);
```

Here, I create 3 variables containing primary, lighter and darker colors based on the primary color defined in the theme above.

Note that your lighter and darker colors must be based on a color from your palette. You can't just pick a random color (Even if it is a color from angular. For a red color here, you will have to use `$custom-warn`). If you still need to lighten or darken a color out of the palette, there is still scss `lighten` and `darken` mixins allowing you to do that:

`lighten($myColor, 30%)`, same for `darken`.

For this theme and variables to works, you need to import `theme.scss` in `styles.scss` and wherever you want to use your custom variables, you will have to import `variables.scss` and that's all.